# Resize occur window in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

When entering `occur` mode for example `(occur "test")` the frame splits into two windows as shown below:

[image]

As seen the Occur buffer is taking up too much space on the frame, since there is only two matches (for the text "test"). I would like to shrink that window accordingly.

I tried the following code:

```
(defun test-occur ()
  (interactive)
  (occur "test")
  (save-window-excursion
    (other-window 1)
    (let (( win (selected-window))
      (n (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)))
      (h (window-body-height)))
      (let ((delta (- (- h n) 3)))
    (window-resize win (- 0 delta) nil)))))
```

But it does not work (nothing happens with the Occur window)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
 (add-hook 'occur-hook
       (lambda ()
         (save-selected-window
           (pop-to-buffer "*Occur*")
           (fit-window-to-buffer))))
```

Comment: Maybe, one should only allow shrinking of the occur buffer. Otherwise the window of interest might get too small. This should work with constraints for `fit-window-to-buffer` (set with `let`).

Comment: @Tobias -- Maybe.  Depends what you want.  `fit-window-to-buffer` accepts arguments that limit the window size.

Comment: @Tobias It seems like there is an upper limit to the max height that the occur buffer can get with `fit-window-to-buffer` if no `max-height` arg is given. It seems it cannot take more than half of the frame height. However, if you specify a `max-height` argument that restriction is no longer valid..

Comment: @HåkonHægland So it seems that the code from the answer is perfect in its original form. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Seems now that `defadvice` may be better than `add-hook`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919308/strange-behavior-in-occur-mode-hook-in-emacs

Comment: `defadvice` is almost *never* better than `add-hook`.  The latter provides a precise entry point deliberately chosen.  I don't have time to look into your other question (which seems pretty much like the same question, BTW), but a crystal-ball guess would be that you need to ensure that the right window and buffer are selected before you use `fit-window-to-buffer`.

Comment: Note: `fit-window-to-buffer` resizes the buffer vertically by default.  If you need it to resize horizontally, you must `(setq fit-window-to-buffer-horizontally t)` first.