# Strange behavior in occur-mode hook in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to resize the `occur-mode` buffer window to fit the contents of its buffer.

See   [Resize occur window in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913293/resize-occur-window-in-emacs) for more information.

I have added the following hook:

```
(add-hook 'occur-mode-hook
       (lambda ()
         (save-selected-window
           (pop-to-buffer "*Occur*")
       (message-box "ok")
       (fit-window-to-buffer nil 10))))
```

Then I have the following buffer window:

[image]

and I now execute `(occur "test")` which gives me first

[image]

and after pressing the "ok" button I get

[image]

Notice that the occur window has shrunk to a single line in height at the bottom of the frame. This was obviously not what I wanted..

I now enter `(occur "test")` once more in the "t.txt" buffer, and after pressing "ok" to the message-box I get the following:

[image]

So now it suddenly works perfectly. Why is this not working the first time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize occur window in Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913293/resize-occur-window-in-emacs)

Comment: @Drew Not exactly duplicate, but similar ideas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
(defadvice occur (after occur-advice activate)
  "Resize window."
  (save-selected-window
    (pop-to-buffer "*Occur*")
    (fit-window-to-buffer nil 10)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I get error `(void-function async-start)`.. Note that the `message-box` was just for debugging purposes. The problem is still there even if I remove the line `(message-box "ok")` ..

Comment: You need to get the async package.

Comment: I reproduced your problem with the code you gave, and the code that I give doesn't
raise a problem.

Comment: Ok :) If you remove the line `(message-box "ok")` do you still get the problem?

Comment: No problem, but only because I already have an occur-mode hook (so yours is the second one). There is a problem with `emacs -q`

Comment: The reason is that `occur-mode` is called in `occur-1` before the matches are collected.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the important part is to keep the call to `fit-window-to-buffer` within the `save-selected-window`.